# Binding issues in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

i am pretty new to knockoutjs. I have a set of buttons clubbed under different fieldsets. I have bound the buttons to a single observable to enable or disable the buttons. On clicking a button under a fieldset i want only the set of buttons under that fieldset to be disabled. How do i do it through knockout.

I have created a fiddle for this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9G8sD/) trying to explain my problem

Thanks.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
<fieldset>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: $data.item">
        <li class="list">
            <input type="button" data-bind="value: $data.title, enable: $root.isEnabled, click: $root.buttonClicked"
            />
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9G8sD/1/). Hope it will helps you for what you want to achieve.

Below is the html code, notice here we used `disable` binding to disable buttons.

```
  <ul data-bind="foreach: Buttons">
    <li class="list">
       <input type="button" data-bind="value: Title, 
                                       click: $root.SetSelectedButton, 
                                       disable: $root.SelectedButton() === $data"
        />
     </li>
   </ul>
```

**EDIT**

Sorry i missed your point in which you mentioned that you want to disable set of buttons. Here is the another fiddle which is the next version of the previous fiddle. In this fiddle you can enable or disable the set of buttons :

[**Updated working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9G8sD/3/)